# Np Random Choice with list of probability distributions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, probability

I have a set of actions [0,1,2,3] and a policy which is a series of probabilities for each action like [[0.5, 0.4, 0.05, 0.05]...].

How would it be possible to use np.random.choice (or something similar) which chooses from my actions array for each probability distribution and returns the list of choices?

For a concrete example:

```
actions = [0, 1, 2, 3]
probs = [[0.5, 0.4, 0.05, 0.05], [0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.8]]

*magic*

output = [0, 3]
```

Edit: Sorry I wasnt clear before, I am looking for a way to do this which is efficient without a loop if possible. My current code uses a loop and it makes generating many episodes at a time extremely slow.

Comment: The probabilities in the second element of `probs` don't add up to 1. Is this intentional?

Comment: It was intended to be 0.05, all probabilities in this array sum to 1

Comment: Use the `random` libray's `choices` allows you to specify weights.  [Docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

Answer (score 1):

`np.random.choice` can take in a [`p` parameter](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) that does what you want:

> **p: *1-D array-like, optional***
>
> The probabilities associated with each entry in a. If not given, the sample assumes a uniform distribution over all entries in a.

Then, you can achieve the desired output by:

```py
actions = [0, 1, 2, 3]
probs = [[0.5, 0.4, 0.05, 0.05], [0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.8]]

output = [np.random.choice(actions, p=prob) for prob in probs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `rng.choice` for each row separately.

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng()
output = [rng.choice(len(actions), p=x) for x in probs]
```